# identifying mouse double click or two single clicks based on coordinates

Tags: c++, windows

I'm sending mouseclicks to an ActiveX control in C++ one after the other (I'm using AutoDesk Design Review (a CAD system) and sending the clicks to draw an arc).

The only problem I'm having is that if two of the clicks are near each other it registers as a double click. 
Is there a value in Windows which determines if the clicks' coordinates make it a double click?

e.g. If the coordinates are less than 10 pixels apart it's a double click, otherwise it's two single clicks.

I cannot intercept the click or cancel the click event in the ActiveX control so I need to stop it firing before.

Many thanks

Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows API does provide a way to determine the double-click time and the double-click rectangle:

- [`GetDoubleClickTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646258.aspx) to get the double-click time.
- [`GetSystemMetrics()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385.aspx) with the `SM_CXDOUBLECLK` index to get the rectangle width.
- `GetSystemMetrics()` with the `SM_CYDOUBLECLK` index to get the rectangle height.

According to [the MSDN documentation for mouse input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645601):

> **Double-Click Messages**
>
> The system generates a double-click message when the user clicks a
>   mouse button twice in quick succession. When the user clicks a button,
>   the system establishes a rectangle centered around the cursor hot
>   spot. It also marks the time at which the click occurred. When the
>   user clicks the same button a second time, the system determines
>   whether the hot spot is still within the rectangle and calculates the
>   time elapsed since the first click. If the hot spot is still within
>   the rectangle and the elapsed time does not exceed the double-click
>   time-out value, the system generates a double-click message.

This should be sufficient information for detecting double-mouse clicks.

Comment: That is exactly it! I just compare the two coordinates I have and if the difference is less than the rectangle then I just call `Sleep(DoubleClickTime())`.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The value by which Windows determines if two clicks are one double or two single clicks is by timing. I don't think there is something in the API that distinguishes them by relative coordinates.